# Solr - highlighting for a field query

Tags: solr

I'm working with Solr 4.3 and it seems that the highlighting component doesnt work with filter queries (`fq`).

I have tested it with simple query field (`q`), and it worked perfectyly.

So how do I do to get highlighting in the fields in which I have searched using filter queries (`fq`)?

**P.S :** From this thread [Filtered results highlighting with Solr 1.4, 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733784/filtered-results-highlighting-with-solr-1-4-1-5), I have concluded that this feature wasnt available in Solr 1.4. And I know that it's possible to do it manually in the client (`UI`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a work around for this you can specify the query to use when highlighting via the [hl.q](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.q) parameter. This will allow you specify the query to be used just for highlighting purposes, in your case just include your filter query (`fq`) parameters as part of the normal query option(`q`). Since this only applies to the highlighting, it should not have any negative impact on your normal query performance, etc.